# "object reference not set to an instance of an object" in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, data-modeling

I'm new to Linq and had to take over a former colleagues project. I've been searching, but I am still a bit stumped on this problem...

I have the following code:

```
var q = db.v_QCData.OrderByDescending(e => e.DataID).Take(MAX_WAFER_LIST);

QcWaferList = null;
if (q != null)
{
    QcWaferList = q.ToList();
```

were db refers to a data model. This works great some of the time, so I know the model is fine, but at other times at ToList(), I get Object reference not set to an Instance of an object. I can't understand why it should be empty some of the time and not others. So I tried this:

```
bool has = db.v_QCData.Any();
```

That returns true, but what I can't understand is how it can have data in it, but not return any data. Any advice at all is appreciated.

EDIT:
line 162 is q.ToList();

> Stack Trace: at System.Data.EntityKey.AddHashValue(Int32 hashCode,
>   Object keyValue)\r\n   at System.Data.EntityKey.GetHashCode()\r\n   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T
>   obj)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey
>   key)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey
>   key, TValue& value)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.TryGetEntityEntry(EntityKey
>   key, EntityEntry& entry)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2
>   constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)\r\n
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper
>   shaper)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()\r\n
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   collection)\r\n   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at
>   Solar1366Tech.LaserQCHMI.ViewModels.MachineViewModel.UpdateWaferList()
>   in c:\TFS2012\Direct
>   Wafer\DWWF03\Solar1366Tech.LaserQCHMI\Solar1366Tech.LaserQCHMI\ViewModels\MachineViewModel.cs:line
>   162

Comment: What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: If this is your actual code, it seems like 'e' is sometimes null. It's definitely not 'q' being null. Do you add new items to the db.v_QCData that are null?

Comment: no, new items are only inserted via stored procedures which always creates a dataID etc.

Comment: Do your procs return duplicate IDs? There seems to be an issue generating a hash/key for the items it returns.. Are you overriding `GetHashCode` in your entities?

Comment: It could be that one of the members of your entity is marked as non-null, but there is a value in the database that is null. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403390/why-am-i-getting-a-nullreferenceexception-in-system-data-entity-dll-entity-fram and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168136/entity-framework-nullreferenceexception-calling-tolist

Comment: That's a good point, I'm going over the data model now to see if there is a nullable conflict.

Comment: If that's the case, post a comment to that effect, and this can be marked as a duplicate of one of the questions I linked.